# Book I read a very long time ago where magic was called "charm"

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book I read maybe 20 years ago. I don't remember a great deal but the magic in the book was called *charm*. At one point someone tracked another person using *charm* by putting their hair into a locket. Wasps played a part in the book at some point.

There were floating islands with guns that used *charm* to fire and the protagonist was male.

Answer (score 6):

Coudl this be [The Dark Shore](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1199871.The_Dark_Shore) by A.A. Attanasio? The magical system is based on 'charm' which people use to (amongst other things) make floating cities

> At the time of the Conquest, a loaf of bread in most dominions cost a newt's-eye. Small as a child's pinky nail and lustrous black with vermilion and emerald razor lines, the hex-gem known as newt's-eye carried the smallest possible charge of Charm—just enough to keep a healthy person awake one night, to heal a small wound, to boil three cups of blue tea, thread radiance through seven nights, stir a wisp of breeze for several hours, or buy an excellent loaf of nut bread still steaming on the baker's palette.

and

> Dogbrick rubbed his head where the curb had kissed him and blinked,
>   perplexed, finding little to remember of Arwar Odawl. A floating city
>   far to the south. He knew of it only because of its famous brandy of
>   the same name—and also, of course, because it was renowned as the
>   oldest city on Irth.